# How to generate a uniformly distributed point in an annular area?

Tags: probability, geometry

Suppose a point is uniformly distributed in an annular region whose inner radius is $R_m$ and outer radius is $R_M$.
Distance from the point to the center is $r$, and the pdf I derived is
$f_\ge(r)=\frac{2r}{R_M^2-R_m^2}$
by using conditional probability.

If the point is distributed within a circle with radius $R$, it can be generated like

```
angle = 2*pi*random()
dist = R*sqrt(random())
xpos = dist*cos(angle)
ypos = dist*sin(angle)
```

But for annular area, `dist = (RM-Rm)*sqrt(random()) + Rm` doesn't match the distance distribution well. So how to generate the point in annular area?

Comment: Are you familiar with the inverse transform method?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling

Comment: @awkward I read the wiki just now. Do you mean getting the inverse CDF
firstly, and then generating a random value __x__ from uniform distribution, finally plugging __x__ into the inverse CDF to get the desired random value?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @awkward My native method is generating a random value from uniform distribution, and if the value is smaller than the inner radius (ratio), generating it repeatedly. The mean of these generated values is very close to theoretic mean.

Answer (score 1):

PDF is 
$$f(r)={2r\over R_M^2 - R_m^2}$$ as you stated.

CDF is $$F(x)=\int_{R_m}^x f(r)dr = {x^2-R_m^2\over R_M^2-R_m^2}.$$
To generate desired `dist`, see [Inverse transform sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling)

The inverse function of $F(x)$ is
$$x=\sqrt{u(R_M^2-R_m^2)+R_m^2}.$$ 
Your `dist` should be

```
dist = sqrt(random()*(RM*RM-Rm*Rm) + Rm*Rm)
```